# Triangle inequality problem with equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

How does one prove that, for any reals $x,y$ , there holds the equality

$$|x|+|y|+||x|-|y|| = |x-y|+|x+y|\quad?$$

I have tried this using both the reverse and triangle inequalities, but I cannot get the equality between the two expressions.

Comment: Check it is true for $0 \le y \le x$ and for $0 \le -y \le x$ and then see these imply it true for all $x$ and $y$ (you can swap $x$ and $y$, or change both their signs simultaneously, without affecting the conclusion).

Comment: In fact, the equation is invariant under the transformations $(x, y) \mapsto (y, x)$ and $(x, y) \mapsto (-x, -y)$, reducing the number of cases required.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to worry about **two** cases: if $|x|\geq |y|$, then both sides equal $2|x|$ and, conversely, if $|x|<|y|$, then both sides equal $2|y|$.

In the above observation, the LHS is simple to see. As for the RHS, you can square it:
$$
\text{RHS}^2=(x-y)^2+(x+y)^2+2|x-y||x+y|\\
=2x^2+2y^2+2|x^2-y^2|=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
4x^2&\text{if }|x|\geq |y|,\\
4y^2&\text{if }|x|< |y|.
\end{array}\right.
$$

Comment: sorry, I just miss why there is equality in the your last line, instead of an inequality?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what puzzles you.

Answer (score 0):

For any $w$, $|w|=|-w|$. For this reason,

1. Replacing $y$ by $-y$ does not change the left or right expression.
2. Replacing $x$ by $-x$ neither, because $|-x-y|+|-x+y|=|x+y|+|x-y|$.

If the signs do not matter, then it suffices to establish the equality for $x, y\ge0$:
$$x+y+|x-y|=|x-y|+x+y.$$